# Need help to check my grammar

Tags: grammar

Can you help me to check if my grammar is okay in this sentence:
"Implemented data visualization (charts) about the number of recovering and deaths from coronavirus."
Thanks!

I have absolute numbers about the number of recovering and deaths.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please note that this is not a proofreading service. If you can [edit] your post to identify a specific point of grammar or usage which leads you to believe the phrasing is correct or not, as well as the context, we may be able to assist. For additional guidance, I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: Hello.
Thanks for your answer.
I should describe in a few words an application that I implemented.
I used charts for display the amount of recovers people and deaths from the corona virus.

Comment: Without more details this is hard to answer. For instance when you say amount recovered do you mean absolute numbers, a proportion, rate per 1000 person years, or something else? We usually write coronavirus as a single word.

Comment: Thanks.
The amount of recovered as absolute numbers.

(I have numbers of specific deaths and recovers from coronavirus and I display it on the chart.
I would like to use in the sentence the words "data visualization".

The sentence I would like to check is:
"Implemented data visualization of the amount recovered and deaths from coronavirus"

Which means "I built a software program = (implemented) to display data (data visualization) of the amount recovered and deaths from coronavirus.

Thanks.

Comment: @user127826 Please [edit] your post to include all the relevant information, rather than posting comments, which are ephemeral. I will repeat my recommendation to take the [tour] and read the [help] to better understand how to use the site.

Comment: I think you mean 'the numbers [of people] recovering'. _Amount_ is used with uncountable nouns.

Comment: Thanks.
I edited my post.
But it still sounds bad the sentence :
 "Implemented data visualization (charts) about the number of recovering and deaths from coronavirus."
Can you help me revise it or let me know what's wrong with the grammar?

Comment: (You forgot to include my name, so I only saw your last comment by chance.) _The number of recovering_ still doesn't make sense. You could say _the numbers of those recovering and of those dying_ or _the numbers of people who recovered and those who died_.